# Inclusion exclusion problem multiple choice and union

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

7 Cards are drawn from a pack of cards (52) no returns.
Defining these events:
S - not getting spades in those 7 cards
H - not getting hearts in those 7 cards
D -  '     '    diamonds '   '   '   '
C -  '     '    clubs    '   '   '   '

What is the probability:  $P(S \cup H \cup D \cup C)$  mean?

1) probability that all the events are chosen in the 7 cards
2) probability that at least one event is chosen in 7 cards.

Because it's union, it seems right the $1$ is correct however it's literally impossible that 7 cards are picked and all of them have no shape?! I mean, 7 cards are drawn and no hearts diamond clubs and spades?! that's impossible!
However I am not sure...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are events, $P(A \cup B)$ is the probability that $A$ happens or that $B$ happens. So $P(S \cup H \cup D \cup C)$ is the probability that there is some suit that doesn't show up ever in the 7 cards.

Comment: based on your answer the answer is 2 right? thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Please mark answer as accepted if your question has been resolved.

Comment: of course I will, however I need to wait 8 minutes for some reason